# Specify an `int` value in Kubernetes ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to specify `int` values in ConfigMap? When I try to specify a port number I get the following error.

```
error: error validating "my-deployment.yml": error validating data: expected type int, for field spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort, got string; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Here is the sample config file I am using:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: poweramp-email-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: poweramp-email-service
        env:
          - name: SERVICE_PORT_NUM
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: stg-config
                key: poweramp-email-service.port
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: my-service.port
```

And here is the simple `stg.properties` file I am using to generate the ConfigMap using the command: `kubectl create configmap stg-config --from-file stg.properties`

```
my-service.port=9513
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use configmap values in `spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort` I'm afraid, it's for configuration values.

The options you can use it for (specified in [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/)) are

- As an environment variable
- As a command line config flag (using environment variables)
- Using the volume plugin.

If you want to make the port configurable for your deployment/pod, you might consider using [Helm](http://helm.sh/). Helm allows you to use Go templates in your manifests/definitions, and then you can override them upon invocation.

Take this [MySQL Chart template as an example](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/mysql/templates/deployment.yaml), you could set the port here as a config option like so:

```
ports:
  - name: mysql
  containerPort: {{ default 3306 .Values.mysqlPort }}
```

and then from there, set this value in your [values.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/mysql/values.yaml)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with setting port number as env variables. 
I have two services where ServiceB should connect to ServiceA.
The error was

/opt/service/config.yml has an error:
  * Incorrect type of value at: serviceAPort; is of type: String, expected: Integer
My config.yml contains something like this 
- serviceAPort: "${SERVICEA_PORT!'9091'}"

Kubernetes was creating an environment variable SERVICEA_PORT in a format which  had Protocol:IP:port. This could not be parsed to an int by ServiceB

I realised this upon using the 'printenv' in ServiceB pod and overrode it with the following config

```
env:
  - name : SERVICEA_PORT
    value: 9091
```

Basically, it was a conflict because of env variables created by k8s out of the box.