# How to Inject Environment Variables into Kubernetes Pods Before Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to inject container port from an environment variable inside my pod. How to do that?

Have been through the documentation, Links:- 
1. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/
2. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: $(MY_CONTAINER_PORT)
      env:
        - name: MY_CONTAINER_PORT
          value: 80
```

```
error: error validating "nginx-pod-exposed-through-env.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort.containerPort: got "string", expected "integer"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: HI, perhaps you need to use "80" rather than using just 80

Comment: I tried this already, doesn't work. :(

Comment: You're trying to do a wrong thing. There is no relation between environmental variable and container's port number. The environmental variable is accessible inside the container after the container starts. The container's  port describes the configuration to create the container.  It would be easier to answer your question if you will describe a bit more what are your needs

Comment: @YuriG. So I got this question in CKAD exam where the question states that I need to declare the container port as env variable and then use this env variable to expose my container. I didn't know how to solve this and documentation is helping so I just wanna understand how to use env variable to expose my specific container port.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Thanks for the input, i tired it and it's still the same thing. I think my approch is wrong in this case, do you have any idea how to expose specific containers port using env variable

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to specify the environment variable value as a port number, you’re trying to do the opposite. Check this page for more info https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962722/8600836) answers your question as expected -

Answer (score 4):

A way to accomplish this would be to use a templating tool such as [ytt](https://get-ytt.io/). With ytt you would turn your manifest into a template like:

```
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: #@ data.values.port
```

And then supply a `values.yml` like:

```
#@data/values
---
port: 8080
```

Assuming the original template is named `test.yml` we could run `ytt` like so to generate the output:

```
$ ytt -f test.yml -f values.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

The ytt utility then lets us override the data values one the command line with `--data-value` (or `-v` for short). An example changing to port 80:

```
$ ytt -v port=80 -f test.yml -f values.yml            
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

Your original question sounded like you wanted to use environment variables. This is supported with `--data-values-env`. An example using prefix `MYVAL`:

```
$ export MYVAL_port=9000
$ ytt --data-values-env MYVAL -f test.yml -f values.yml   
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9000
```

You can then combine `ytt` and `kubectl` to create and apply resources:

```
ytt --data-values-env MYVAL -f test.yml -f values.yml | kubectl apply -f-
```

Additional information on injecting data into ytt templates is at https://github.com/k14s/ytt/blob/develop/docs/ytt-data-values.md.

Comment: The syntax for this has changed. The proper way to do it now is: 
`ytt -f . --data-values-env MYVAL -f test.yml -f values.yml | kubectl apply -f-`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use environment variables defined for the pod to be used to expose the port. Kubernetes expects the value of container port to be integer, but since you gave $(MY_CONTAINER_PORT), it says string values are not allowed.

The right configuration would be,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

However, if you still need environment variables to be specified as containerPort, its better to use kubernetes package manager like **helm**, or run a shell script to your yaml before deploying to kubernetes, preferrably with `envsubstr` that will resolve the environment variable and regenerate the yaml file with the env variable substituted for containerPort. Perhaps this github [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787) might help you why kubectl will never support variable substitution.

Comment: `sed` is useful for pipeline variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Below example has an environment variable "**PASSWORD**"

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
    env:
    - name: PASSWORD
      value: "password"
```

Comment: gr8, but how do u use it in a spring boot app ?  i m trying to use kubectl secrets expose on a pod  using this dependency: spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config,  i got this exception : io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException